# PHP detect if column value is DATE or DATETIME

Tags: php, date, datetime

Can I check with PHP if the given value is `DATE` or `DATETIME` format?

```
function decodeTimestamp($var)
{
    return date("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($var));
}
```

What I'd like to do is following.

```
if $var == "2015-09-04" then return "4.9.2015"
if $var == "2015-09-04 14:00:00" then return "4.9.2015 14:00"
```

Comment: Could you use the type operator "instanceof"?
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

Comment: You can use date function for your requirement. Try using my code and reply me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match` as

```
function decodeTimestamp($var)
{
    if(preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/',$var)){
        return date("d.m.Y", strtotime($var));   
    }elseif(preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\h\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/',$var)){
        return date("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($var));   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working very fine. I thought that `preg_match` would be the solution.